# Short story in which a man on a train learns how to mentally control the rolling of dice

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

A long time ago, I read a short story in which there was a man on a train who learns how to control the rolls that come up on dice. The way it's phrased is that he maintains a certain pattern in his mind, and as a result, the rolls of the dice always come up totaling seven. The story implied that the ability wasn't general telekinesis; it only influenced chance events into coming out a certain way.

The story ended with the implication that this would be a world-changing event, but it didn't go into the details.

If I had to guess, then I'd claim that Ray Bradbury wrote it, but I really have no idea. I read it some time around 1997, but the book or anthology was rather older than that. As best I can remember it had a 50s-to-60s feel.

Anyone have any idea what story this was?

Comment: Probably not what you're looking for, but in Greg Egan's _Quarantine_, technology is used that allows a person to prevent the collapse of quantum wavefunctions on a macroscopic level as long as desired, and then to consciously choose which resulting state things will collapse to, effectively providing human-controlled luck.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This sounds similar to the plot of [Kurt Vonnegut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurt_Vonnegut)'s first short story, "[Report on the Barnhouse Effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Report_on_the_Barnhouse_Effect)", though in this story the protagonist (one Professor Arthur Barnhouse) eventually ends up doing quite a bit more than controlling dice -- but the way in which he accomplishes it sounds very similar to your description.

Comment: +1 Very good odds on this one; it appears in the anthology "Welcome to the Monkey House" and I am certain that I read WttMH as part of an anthology at a similar time. I will check it out.

Comment: Definitely it! Thank you. It's still a good read also.